# Ionic - Can't click on subheader

Tags: android, frameworks, ionic-framework

I've a problem with my subheader, this is a search bar and under this i've tabs. 
I can click on my tabs but not on the surch bar and i don't know why...

That's my view:

```
<ion-header-bar class="bar bar-subheader bar-positive padding item-input-inset">

    <label class="item-input-wrapper">
        <i class="icon ion-ios7-search placeholder-icon"></i>
        <input type="search" placeholder="Recherche" ng-model="searchFilter" autocorrect="off" ng-change="scrollTop()">
    </label>
    <button class="button button-clear" ng-click="searchFilter=''">
        Annuler
    </button>

</ion-header-bar>

<ion-nav-view>
    <ion-tabs class="tabs-top tabs-striped">
        <ion-tab title="Ok" class="balanced">
            <ion-nav-view name="tab-problems" class="">
                <ion-content class="">

                    <h1>Test 1</h1>

                </ion-content>
            </ion-nav-view>
        </ion-tab>
        <ion-tab title="Warning" class="energized">
            <ion-nav-view name="tab-problems" class="">
                <ion-content class="">

                    <h1>Test 2</h1>

                </ion-content>
            </ion-nav-view>
        </ion-tab>

    </ion-tabs>
</ion-nav-view>
```

EDIT:

When i have this:

```
<ion-nav-view has-header="true" has-tabs="true">
    <ion-tabs class="tabs-top tabs-striped">
        <ion-tab title="Critique" class="assertive">
            <ion-nav-view name="tab-problems" class="">
                <ion-content class="">
                    <ion-refresher
                                   pulling-text="Mettre à jour..."
                                   on-refresh="doRefresh()">
                    </ion-refresher>

                    <h1>test</h1>

                </ion-content>
            </ion-nav-view>
        </ion-tab>
    </ion-tabs>
</ion-nav-view>
```

I can see the content but i can't click on search,  when i do this:

```
    <ion-content>
    <ion-nav-view has-header="true" has-tabs="true">
        <ion-tabs class="tabs-top tabs-striped">
            <ion-tab title="Critique" class="assertive">
                <ion-nav-view name="tab-problems" class="">
                    <ion-content class="">
                        <ion-refresher
                                       pulling-text="Mettre à jour..."
                                       on-refresh="doRefresh()">
                        </ion-refresher>

                        <h1>test</h1>

                    </ion-content>
                </ion-nav-view>
            </ion-tab>
        </ion-tabs>
    </ion-nav-view>
</ion-content>
```

I can't see the title but i can click on search.